# CompletableFuture runs out of order

Tags: java, asynchronous, future

I have the following code in Java (I use Oracle Java 17):

```
package com.test;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Solution {
    public void startCompletableFutureExample() {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                    System.out.println("async operation");
                })
                .completeOnTimeout(
                        timeout(), 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private Void timeout() {
        System.out.println("timeout happens");
        return null;
    }
}
```

when I call the `startCompletableFutureExample()` method I have the following output:

```
timeout happens
async operation
```

while I'd expect to get the only one as timeout has not been even close:

```
async operation
```

Why do I have method `completeOnTimeout` to be run before `runAsync`? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The first argument of `completeOnTimeout` is the fallback value itself. That means it's evaluated eagerly. It has to be in order to be passed to the method as an argument. In other words, the `completeOnTimeout` **stage** is _not_ executing prematurely, you're just printing `"timeout happens"` too early. If you want to lazily compute the fallback value, use `orTimeout` followed by `exceptionally` (or `handle` or `whenComplete` if you want to handle the result or error in the same stage).

Comment: Thank you for that answer - I was looking for `handle` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question - if it is necessary to run asynchronously CompletableFuture or cancel it by timeout expiration, as [Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw) suggested it is better to use `handle` method. I've got the desired behavior with the following code:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class Solution {
    public void startCompletableFutureExample() {
        CompletableFuture<String> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return "async operation";
        }).orTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        f.handleAsync((msg, ex) -> {
            if (ex instanceof TimeoutException) {
                System.out.println("timeout happens");
                f.cancel(true);
            } else {
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
            return null;
        });

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I run it, I'll get a timeout reached first and thus the output would be only:

```
timeout happens
```

However if I set `Thread.sleep(5)` instead of `Tread.sleep(50)`, I will get only:

```
async operation
```

which is an expected value.

Comment: Note the call to `f.cancel(true)` has no effect here. In order for the `handleAsync` stage to be executing, the parent stage, which is `f` in this case, _must_ have already completed. Thus, cancelling `f` does nothing. And keep in mind that `f` is the `orTimeout` stage, not the `supplyAsync` stage. Additionally, passing `true` to `cancel` indicates you expect a thread to be interrupted and stop the background task which timed out. That's unfortunately not how `CompletableFuture` works.

Comment: See the documentation of [`CompletableFuture#cancel(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel(boolean)) for more information.

Comment: Yup, you right, that call has no real meaning - `f` is finished at that when I call it, so that call is definitely redundant.

Continue thinking then it means that `f` has 2 stages - `supplyAsync(...)` which is finished either by (hopefully) successful completion, or by next stage, which is `orTimeout(...)`. When I handle the exception and checking if it is a `TimeoutException` instance, it means that `f` is completed and I am gathering data whether it was completed successfully or by the next step - `orTimeout(...)`.

Thank you Slaw!

Answer (score 1):

Used method `#completeOnTimeout(T value, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` accepts value instead of some sort of supplier. This means that this value is computed before passing it into the method.

For case of executing some logic only upon timeout - `#get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` can be utilized.

Simplified version of the code:

```
try {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("async operation");
    }).get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    System.out.println("timeout happens");
}
```

Such approach will allow code execution upon encountering TimeoutException, which is thrown when future is not completed in specified time

Comment: Another option, if you want to stay within the "chain" of futures, is to use e.g., `orTimeout` followed by `exceptionally` where it's checked if the error is a `TimeoutException`.

Comment: I thought about it actually and that was my guess, so thank you for confirming it. However using `get` operation will block execution and if I need to work with the stream of data, where futures are supposed to be resolved independently or get cancelled by timeout which may be a minute.

That's not what I expecting, but thank you!